# Delete old records from firefox sqlite databases

Tags: linux, firefox, sqlite

I have some big sqlite3 databases in ~/.mozilla/firefox/profilename

Notably places.sqlite (12 MB) and urlclassifier3.sqlite (33 MB).

Is it possible to truncate them and wipe out the oldest records in them?

Of course I could just wipe them completely, but that's not my goal - I just want to minimize the size of those files while keeping the newest records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `places.sqlite` database contains all your bookmarks and history -- you can just remove unneeded history from Firefox. `urlclassifier3.sqlite` is a list of phishing site URLs, and you can delete it completely -- while anti-phishing is enabled, it will be re-populated automatically (it may be smaller afterwards, so deletion is not useless).

If you want to disable anti-phishing completely, you can turn off these two checkboxes in settings:
[image: firefox settings]

If you want to optimize them even more, check [this article](http://gettingclever.com/2008/06/vacuum-your-firefox-3.html).

Comment: The above site (gettingclever.com) is dead. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20121107075127/http://www.gettingclever.com/2008/06/vacuum-your-firefox-3.html) is an archived copy of the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQLite you can run this command:

```sh
echo 'DELETE FROM moz_historyvisits
WHERE visit_date < strftime("%s", "now", "-5 month") * 1000000; VACUUM;' |
sqlite3 places.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [article](http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2009/08/vacuum-firefox-databases-for-better-performance-now-with-no-restart/), all you have to do is go into `Tools=>Error Console` and paste in `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsPIPlacesDatabase).DBConnection.executeSimpleSQL("VACUUM");`

Comment: I know about the VACUUM command in sqlite, I'm doing it manually sometimes. But AFAIK it only compresses the filesize by removing the empty gaps, it doesn't purge oldest records from the database, which is my primary goal.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (if you're using Windows) is to use the already-useful-for-other-reasons [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) (AKA CrapCleaner).  It includes an option to clean up and compress the Firefox databases as part of its regular cleaning tasks.

Comment: I thought it was obvious from my question that I'm not using Windows. Please see the location of the user directory.

Comment: @vtest: Nope, not obvious.  That's what tags are for.